# Why accuracy of my image segmentation model does not change?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm studying on histopathologic image segmentation project. I built a model for that, but accuracy is always staying same across the epochs. It is always 0.5000. I need to improve it. I changed learning rate, batch size, epochs(I tried to increase/decrease it), optimizer (I tried SGD, RMSPROP, ADAM) etc before. But there is still no change. What should I do for that? Thanks in advance for your help.

***Here are my codes for the model:***

```
depth=3
class Net:
    @staticmethod
    def build(img_width, img_height, depth, classes):
        model = Sequential()
        chanDim = -1
        inputShape =(input_shape)
        model.add(SeparableConv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",input_shape = inputShape))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        # (CONV => RELU => POOL) * 2
        model.add(SeparableConv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))   
        model.add(SeparableConv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

     
        model.add(SeparableConv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(SeparableConv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(SeparableConv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        
       
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(256))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

      
        model.add(Dense(64))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))
        model.add(Dropout(1))

        model.summary()
        return model
```

```
    model_history = model.fit_generator(img_train_gen,
              steps_per_epoch = train_steps,  
              epochs=10, 
              verbose=1, 
              validation_data=img_val_gen,
              validation_steps= val_steps)
model.save('nucleiproject.h5')
```

***The results of accuracy:***

```
64/64 [==============================] - 69s 1s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/10
64/64 [==============================] - 66s 1s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/10
64/64 [==============================] - 65s 1s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 4/10
64/64 [==============================] - 63s 982ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 5/10
64/64 [==============================] - 64s 997ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 6/10
64/64 [==============================] - 63s 979ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 7/10
64/64 [==============================] - 67s 1s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 8/10
64/64 [==============================] - 67s 1s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 9/10
64/64 [==============================] - 69s 1s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 10/10
64/64 [==============================] - 75s 1s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
```

Comment: Why `Dropout(1)` at the end? Do you realize what `Dropout(1)` means in practice?

Comment: I wanted to reduce overfitting. Also, it gives the error `InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [16,2] vs. [16,64]` without Dropout(1). Shouldn't I use this? @desertnaut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem,

Dropout layer randomly sets some of the the output values of the previous layer to prevent overfitting. The dropout value must always be less than 1, for the model to train properly, and it is quite unusual to have a dropout as the final layer

So try removing the final Dropout Layer

This might help